# RxJava2 - Error returned by child Single is propagated despite handling in parent Single

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android

So, I have a `Repository` class, which has a `search()` method which creates a zipped Single and returns data to a listener.

Inside of this method, I need to call 4 services and zip their results. The services return different data types, from which I build the `SearchResult` object.

The method looks like this:

```
fun search() {
    Single.just(SearchResult.Builder())
        .zipWith(
            service1.search()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .onErrorReturnItem(emptyList()),
            { result, data -> result.apply { this.data1 = data } })
        .zipWith(
            service2.search()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .onErrorReturnItem(emptyList()),
            { result, data -> result.apply { this.data2 = data } })
        // Other two services done in the same way
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { listener.onSearchComplete(it.build()) },
            { listener.onSearchFailed() })
}
```

The implementation of `search()` in the services looks like this:

```
fun search(): Single<List<DataTypeX>> =
    Single.create<List<DataTypeX>> { subscriber ->
        makeNetworkRequest()
        ?.let{
            //logic omitted for clarity
            subscriber.onSuccess(it)
        } ?: subscriber.onError(IllegalStateException())
```

The problem is the last line. **When this network call fails and the response is *null*, the `IllegalStateException` will be propagated and crash the app, instead of being silently caught by `onErrorReturnItem(emptyList())`.**

Is there any reason for this? Am I misunderstanding the idea behind onErrorReturnItem()?

Comment: I can't see any mistake. Please check what the stacktrace of the IllegalStateException points to. Also try `tryOnError` instead of `onError` to see if the reason of the app crash is due to undeliverable errors inside `Single.create`.

Comment: The stacktrace is for the empty IllegalStateException and points to the line with "subscriber.onError()". I will try the method you mentioned once I am back in the office :-)

Comment: I just stumbled over this, did you resolve it already? Does `listener.onSearchFailed()` eventually crash the app?